# Rotation counterclockwise

Tags: matrices, rotations

> Let $A_{\theta}$ be rotation counterclockwise by $\theta$ as follows:
>   $$A_\theta = \left[ \begin{matrix} \cos(\theta) & -\sin(\theta)\\ \sin(\theta) & \cos(\theta)\end{matrix} \right]$$

We can check easy that $A^{-1}_{\theta}=A_{-\theta}.$

Indeed, using $\cos(-\theta)=\cos(\theta)$ and $\sin(-\theta)=-\sin(\theta)$

$$A_{-\theta}=\left[ \begin{matrix} \cos(-\theta) & -\sin(-\theta)\\ \sin(-\theta) & \cos(-\theta)\end{matrix} \right]=\left[ \begin{matrix} \cos(\theta) & \sin(\theta)\\ -\sin(\theta) & \cos(\theta)\end{matrix} \right]=A^{-1}_{\theta}$$

- In general, could this  hold for :
  $$ \forall n \in \mathbb{Z} ,\quad (A_{\theta})^{n}=A_{n\theta} (*) $$

i'll try by induction

Basis step; $n= 1 \implies A^{1}_{\theta}=A_{\theta}$

Induction step;Assume that, for n =k , (*) works,

show true for n=k+1

Indeed,

\begin{align*}
(A_{\theta})^{n+1}&=(A_{\theta})^{n}(A_{\theta})^{1}\\
&=(A_{n\theta})(A_{\theta}) ( \text{ by assumption of induction })\\
\text{Since :} A_{\theta 1}A_{\theta 2}=A_{\theta1+\theta2} \\
&=(A_{(n+1)\theta})
\end{align*}

but this is just true for $n\in\mathbb{N}$ how can i prove it for $\mathbb{Z}$

Comment: Indeed it is true.Since you have shown it for $n=1$ and $n=-1$, now apply induction on $n$ to complete your proof.

Comment: @Adam For which reason? :-)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is true.

By defination of function $A_{n\theta}$ rotates $n\theta$ in counterclockwise direction.

And $A_\theta$ rotates with angle $\theta$ and $(A_\theta)^n$ is taking composion of $n$ times
as composion of linear function is equivalent to multiplying the coressponding matrices.

**Edit:** Let $T$ be a linear transformation from $R^2$ to $R^2$. (which means that $T$ is such a function that $T(cu+v)=cT(u)+T(v)$ where $c\in R$ and $u,v\in R^2$).

And by linear algebra we know that linear transformation coresponds to matrix multiplication or vice versa i.e. $T(u)=A\vec{u}$.

From that point $$T\circ T \circ...T(u)=A^n \vec u$$ i.e composition of linear transformation corresponds to martix multiplication.

Now, Just notice that ratation with angle $n\theta$ is composion of $n$ times of rotation of $\theta$ and use the fact that rotation is a linear transformation.

Comment: please could you suggest me to reference that talk about this properties in details or could you tell me step by step how can i prove it if you have time and thanks

Comment: ok, I will edit my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Another way;

We can think $R^2$ as complex plain $\mathbb C$ and for any complex $c$ we have

$$c=rcis(\alpha)$$ where $cis(\alpha)=cos(\alpha)+isin(\alpha)$ and $r=|c|$.

Set, $m=cis(\theta)$ then $$cm=rcis(\alpha+\theta)$$ by that equation you see that multiplication by $m$ is rotates $c$ with angle $\theta$. (you can also check that it exactly correspond the matrix multiplication of $x$ and $y$ cordinates )

By De Moivre's formula, $$m^n=cis(n\theta)$$ which shows same result.

Comment: can we prove it by induction ??

Comment: Yes, we can do it.

Comment: For inductive step show that $$\left[ \begin{matrix} \cos(n\theta) & -\sin(n\theta)\\ \sin(n\theta) & \cos(n\theta)\end{matrix} \right]=\left[ \begin{matrix} \cos((n-1)\theta & -\sin((n-1)\theta\\ \sin((n-1)\theta & \cos((n-1)\theta\end{matrix} \right].A_{\theta}$$

Comment: please check my update for induction

Comment: @Adam: for $\mathbb Z$ use this fact $A^{-n}=(A^{-1})^n$